# jSignature height issue on jquery mobile switching between Portrait and Landscape

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

With jSignature on a jquery mobile page, when first viewing it, I can switch back and forth between Portrait and Landscape views on my iphone and the signature box works correctly. I've looked in Web Inspector and see the Canvas width and height change from (254px x 64px)P to (502px x 126px)L...all looks and works well.

However if I leave that page then rotate the device, the canvas get set to 100 x 25px. I believe this is because it is reading 100% for the Parent div, not pixels. When I navigate back to the Signature page, it is squashed, set still at 100 x 25px instead of 254px x 64px. The only fix I found is to rotate the device, which resets it to the correct pixels.

I've tried setting the properties of the jSignature parent div directly within a $(window).on("orientationchange",function():

```
 myw = $(window).width();
 $('#signature').prop("width", myw).css({'width':myw});
```

but no luck.
 I've tried setting the canvas directly:

```
 $('canvas.jSignature').prop({"height": mh, "width": myw}).css({'height':mh+'px'});
```

which does set the correct height when returning to the page, but when I sign and rotate, it deletes the signature (like its re-initializing after these properties are forced upon it).

The signature box needs to remain responsive (specific pixel values are not an option).  Is there a fix for this squashed height value when the device is rotated away from the signature page and returned to it?